# Why are apps excluded from Titanium Backup?

Tags: titanium-backup

I have been using [CM Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ksmobile.cb) for couple of years. A couple of months ago I set Titanium Backup ( Pro - version `7.5.0`) to backup on schedule as shown below ( 3 as maximum backup versions ):

[image: Screenshot]

After the last update of CM Browser, which I didn't like, I uninstalled it, being sure I could switch to the earlier version. Surprisingly, I didn't find *CM Browser backup !*

To doubly verify, I installed CM again and took a manual backup (by force-running the schedule) and sure enough it didn't show up – despite of the "backup completed" toast being shown (no error message in between either). And yes, I've verified that I didn't have any filters set that might be hiding it.

It can't be a version issue of Titanium as the previous version should have retained 3 backups.

**Why is this so? What makes apps "unbackable" ? How do I fix this?**

**Device:** Moto X Play, 6.0.1, stock, rooted

**Edit:**

1. As suggested by Izzy in comments, searched the backup directory and found backups of Browser. Installing the apk from there got me my old Browser version but minus the bookmarks ( Data for `apk`always included in preferences).Backup of newer version also present in `apk`
2. Mailed the developer. Will post updates but meanwhile ideas to troubleshoot are welcome

**Edit 2:** when I took a logcat for the second time (in the process of installing app and forcing a backup), TiBu mysteriously decided to show me CM Browser with all previous versions and data intact. I haven't the faintest idea and will post an answer if the developer clarifies. I have mailed him the logcat. [Pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/bDTq3j58)

You are welcome to post your answers

Comment: It didn't show up in filter *not backed up* also

Comment: In over 5 years using TiBu, I've never seen such. I'd recommend repeating the manual backup while taking a logcat, and reporting to Joël (the dev). Keep us update, please :)

Comment: By the way: with the app not showing up in the list at all, how did you do a manual backup of it? If it doesn't show up in any list, TiBu obviously isn't even aware of it. Also, please check your backup directory if there's anything related to the app.

Comment: Where you configured TiBu should place the backup files. Usually the `TitaniumBackup` directory on your SD card (if not explicitly set up, on the internal one – first thing I do on new devices/installations is to point it to the external card, as I want access to the backups even if "the device dies").

Comment: Thanks, I've integrated some more stuff out of the (now removed) comments. If you repeated the backup while taking a logcat (as suggested), and were able to isolate the corresponding parts: consider putting them to a pastebin (minus any PII, if there are any ;) and link that here. Maybe it rings a bell to someone.

Comment: @izzy : Thanks and added an edit.  Surprising.

Comment: Ugh – indeed. So if you just try hard enough, it will finally show up… Well, most important part of your results: Backups have always been taken, so no data was lost. // And where's your pastebin? ;) // Curious for Joël's reply.

Comment: Izzy: Added pastebin -deleting portions I thought were not relevant . First time i used it so it doesn't allow me to paste in full unless I pay- which I see no reason to at least for now

Comment: Nope. After removing empty lines, it got a lot smaller. Then, TiBu is started in line 1328 (15:22:19.725) – so everything before that is obsolete anyhow. Uninstall of CM Browser at 1696 (15:26:53.563)ff… Ouch. Check for `com.ksmobile.cb`, that app seems to have several issues. There could even lie the reason for TiBu not showing it. ReInstall at 2223 (15:27:33.679). Only TiBu related entry is when MediaScanner finds the backup (`.tar.gz`) at 3263 (15:28:38.655), except for its starting and being brought to foreground. Maybe Joël sees something else, I don't.

Comment: Wow...impressed...thanks. CM family has always been a suspect but I quite like the browser

Comment: No Cheetah on my devices (fetching Garlic, silver bullets, etc. just in case), they're completely bananas. One specific reason against this browser: Flurry Analytics. No, thanks. Much too invasive. And btw used by the other CM apps as well. As to the effectiveness and usefulness of their apps, [read this](https://www.androidpit.com/cheetah-mobile-interview-2-right-to-complain) – they can't even explain it themselves. My personal opinion: it's just about gathering data. Better [pick one of these](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser#group_879) :)

Comment: Thanks *Sir*- uninstalled and going for the first in the list *Privacy Browser*

Comment: Yupp, good choice :) Still: Please keep us updated if Joël responds, especially if he finds something and there's a solution.

Comment: Sure but looks like he has a **team** to take care of things- hope it reaches him or there would be a response. Read up a little on *Flurry* and that little was enough to opt out from their logging- whether it works or not