# Can I restore Titanium App Backups from a phone with Android 4.4 to my Android 6 Phone?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 6.0-marshmallow, restore, data-transfer, titanium-backup

Im backing up My Galaxy Note 2 with Titanium Backup.
Is it possible to restore Apps + App Data on my Huawei P9 running Android 6?
And maybe even more important: Is that adviseable and will work without problems?

Comment: It'll probably work but I advise against restoring **any** system app because they almost all break.

Comment: Bold-underlining: Don't restore system apps *or their data* – neither across devices nor across different ROMs or Android versions. Might have crazy side-effects. When trying, be at least prepared you might have to factory-reset and start over (skipping the problematic app then). And make sure to activate the "Migration mode" in TiBus troubleshooting section. I'm writing that out of personal (bad) experience, so it's not just a theoretical warning.

Comment: @beeshyams is it (dropped)? I didn't check lately. Just browsed the Changelog back to v5.7 (pre-Kitkat) and didn't find a note. But neither do I find "Migration Mode" in *General › Settings › Troubleshooting* (where it was in previous versions). Guess it was renamed: "AUTO, indirect" in "processing mode" (*General › Settings,* in the "Troubleshooting" settings right before the "Troubleshooting" sub-menu) – as that's what it did: Instead of directly copying back  SQLite databases (overwriting existing ones), it tried to replace the data inside (thus keeping table structures).

Comment: @beeshyams just done. Instead of incorporating details from your linked answer, I linked it as "further readings" (so you might gain another upvote from it :) // BTW: My guess is it was never *dropped* (as the Changelog doesn't mention that), but got *renamed* during the "big restructuring" at v6.0. And yes, you're not the only one blaming the UI for being "not really user friendly". I can only guess that, like me, Joël is more the "backend person" than the "UI designer". Maybe one day someone comes to the rescue, helping to care for the latter ;)

Comment: Thanks . +1. Requesting you to delete all earlier comments and this once you read. Aside, still waiting or was waiting for a reply from TiBu on this Q. Don't think it is worth waiting anymore. http://android.stackexchange.com/q/155017/131553

Answer (score 2):

<sup>As requested by beeshyams, I'll sum up my comments to an answer here:</sup>

There should be no problem as long as you stick to ***user apps*** (i.e. apps you've installed yourself – as opposed to apps that came pre-installed with the device). I've done that for years without any issues – though I must admit I've never skipped major Android versions, but always upgraded step-wise (i.e. 2.3 › 4.0 › 4.1/2/3 › 4.4 › 5.x – which means I've skipped 5.0, and maybe some (but not all) of the JellyBeans).

However, it is ***strongly recommended against restoring system apps and their data across different ROMs,*** especially across multiple Android versions, as this almost surely will lead to trouble. I've experienced such in the past when just trying to restore *data* of some system app. So if you need to include system apps and/or their data, first check for alternatives, in this order:

- SMS/MMS, APs, contacts, call lists and some more: Use TiBu's XML backups for those. Restore those XML backups, but never directly the app and its data.
- apps not covered by XML: If you cannot do without, take extra-extra care. Always be prepared you might need to do a factory-reset. Try avoiding the restore of system apps (which came pre-installed) the best you can: those are more often closely integrated with the resp. ROM than not.
  If you really have to restore their data, make it the first thing in your restore process (so the factory-reset doesn't hurt as much), and do it one-by-one each time followed by testing for side-effects. If it breaks something, skip that backup and rather shed some tears<sup>**1**</sup>. If you instead want to follow the hints from the footnotes, make the affected app the first to restore data from after your next factory-reset and only go on when you either succeeded including testing for side-effects – or gave up and did your subsequent factory-reset.

Also see beeshyam's answer on [How to restore from Titanium Backup with file on computer?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/155394/16575) for further details.

---

<sup><sup>**1**</sup></sup><sub>Before abandoning it, you can try enabling some troubleshooting-options: In *General › Settings,* pick the first item in the "Troubleshooting" section (labeled something like "app processing mode") and change that to "AUTO, indirect". That should try to update the tables inside the apps' databases instead of replacing the corresponding SQLite files, thus keeping the table structures intact (if I'm interpreting this correctly that is; in older versions, TiBu had an option called "Migration Mode" at this place, which is gone without a note in the Changelogs – while this item suddenly "popped up", sounding like what "Migration Mode" was supposed to do). You can also check with additional settings from the *Troubeshooting* sub-menu: especially enforcing system SQLite helped in several cases.</sub>