# Restore app data from 4.x in 6.x

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, restore

I have an old phone which I used for a few month when my S4 was broken. I managed to backup and restore the app data from S4 to this phone by just copying `/data/data/appname` - however both devices were 4.x .

Now I have a new phone with 6.0 Marshmallow and I intended to do the same thing - and failed.

Example whatsapp: I copied the old apk, installed it to 6.0 and then (in twrp) replaced `/data/data/com.whatsapp` with the old one.

For testing I also set it to `chmod 777`. Whatsapp shows a notification (A problem with chat history) and if I start whatsapp it closes (crashes?) immediately.

Any idea how to copy the old app data to marshmallow? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you still have the old device and it works properly, I'd advise that you use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to migrate your apps. Check out [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156887/) for more details about it.

Honestly, I have never tried to restore app data between different Android OS major versions (such as 4.X to 6.X in your case), but it's worth a shot. By the way, WhatsApp has its own built-in feature to backup and restore data, in case you were wondering. And please let me know how this turned out, I'm curious to know the outcome for myself.